# How to compare two boxed numbers for equality in .NET?

Tags: .net, numbers, equality

Suppose I have the following, completely pointless code:

```
object val1 = 1;
object val2 = 1l;
```

The below will return false, because the two boxed *objects* aren't the same, as objects they have different types:

```
val1 == val2
```

The same applies for:

```
val1.Equals(val2)
```

Or:

```
Object.Equals(val1, val2)
```

What is the easiest way to compare these in the same way that the following would, considering I **don't know the types at runtime** (and hence cannot cast):

```
1 == 1l;
```

In other words, how do I get a *value* based comparison on two *boxed* numbers?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Why would 1==11 return true no matter how you wrote the expression?

Comment: it's (int)1 == (long)1. he's using an L not an additional 1

Comment: do you know at least if they are always going to be some form of number? (numbers as a tag)

Comment: @JohnFx - what font are you seeing on SO?!

Comment: It's 1==1L, joshcomley didn't heed the compiler warning, "The 'l' suffix is easily confused with the digit '1' -- use 'L' for clarity."

Comment: You are trying to compare a fish and a frog.  You'll have to drown the frog first to make it a meaningful comparison.  Convert.ToInt64 on both will be required to avoid drowning yourself.

Comment: That's funny. When I fixed my code sample to 1l from 11 I got a compiler warning "The l suffix is easily confused with the digit 1 use L for clarity". Apparently it is!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the *dynamic* keyword.  It will resolve the objects to your value types so that you can use the == operator and compare the true values:

```
(dynamic)val1 == (dynamic)val2
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's a specific type of object, you can use the `.Equals()` method to check equality - either one of the standard .Net types which supports it or by adding it to your own objects.

Failing that, you can cast them to a known type if you know in advance what it will be

Good points from cdhowie so...

I may be missing something but you know they're numbers from the title of the question/tags - unless you have some custom types for storing numbers, can't you simply cast everything to Long (or ULong if +ve only) and then compare?

Comment: -1 Does not actually answer the question.  (OP asked how to compare for equality when the types are not known in advance, and also indicates that the `.Equals()` method does not work on boxed numbers of different types.)

Comment: K, downvote removed, but I would like to point out a few more things: (1) Casting to `long` won't always work (what if the boxed numbers were a `double` and a `float` with differing fractional components?) and (2) `.Equals()` will not always work.  For example, this returns false!  `1.Equals(1L);`

Comment: I would like to get the equivalent comparison - some might be `long`, some might be `decimal`, some might be `double` - then I would have to cast all to `double`, but that might truncate my `long`, which I want to avoid

Comment: @joshcomley - In that case, I don't see you're going to be able to do it without testing the types of both and determining if they're comparable before applying the appropriate casts and then comparing... Longs won't catch floats, floats may overflow longs, etc... - You could test if they're both whole numbers and apply long. If they're both fractional, use float - but it's never going to be possible to compare a long with a fraction reliably using the standard data types. You _could_ write your own class which takes in an object in the constructor and sets one of a couple of internal fields..

Comment: @joshcomley [cont] - a long, a float, etc. and overrides the equals operator to take another of your classes - then have some custom logic for the various different scenarios. I'm guessing you'll actually end up with 3 states - equals, unequal, can't compare. I'm assuming it's not possible to avoid having them boxed in the first place? I'm sure you're aware of Long/Integer/etc. `.TryParse()` which will come in handy if you go down this route

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the type then I think you'll have to do some reflection to figure out what means of comparing data is required.

Comment: Note the OP says "I don't know the types at runtime (and hence cannot cast)"

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at **System.ValueType.Equals(obj, obj)**

However, using Reflector you can see that this method specifically returns false if the types don't match.

You could try extend your own method, say, **object.ValueEquals(obj, obj)**, using the code from Reflector and eliminating that check.

Worth a shot i'd say.